# How can I use the WHERE clause to filter a date and range of time?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find customer engagements that occurred at specific date and times,

I think I have the date part correct however I can't seem to set the time right.

```
SELECT EngagementNumber,
       StartDate,
       StartTime
FROM Engagements
WHERE StartDate LIKE '2012-10-%%'
      AND StartTime BETWEEN '12:00:00.0000000' AND '17:00:00.0000000';
```

Comment: sql-server and mysql refers different choose any one of them.

Comment: what is the datatype of StartTime ??

Comment: Provide table definition and sample data set

Comment: I would also question why StartDate and StartTime are in different columns. Is it possible to combine them both into one column in your design?

Answer (score 0):

One reason you have downvotes is because you have chosen to tag your question with 2 databases, but the syntax for each is very different.

Another is that without some "key facts" we are just left guessing. e.g. `what is the datatype of StartTime ??` this is vital to the solution because if data type is `DATE` then this would fail `WHERE StartDate LIKE '2012-10-%%'` but if the data type is `VARCHAR` or similar then it would work (sort of). We also need to know the data type of StartTime.

**So: IF**

1. you are using MySQL
2. The data type of StartDate is Date
3. The data type of StartTime is Time

Below is an example of how your query **might work**, see a demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/505281/3)

**Sample Data (MySQL)**:

```
CREATE TABLE Engagements
    (`EngagementNumber` int, `StartDate` datetime, `StartTime` time)
;

INSERT INTO Engagements
    (`EngagementNumber`, `StartDate`, `StartTime`)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-09-01 00:00:00', '13:14:15'),
    (2, '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '14:15:16'),
    (3, '2017-10-11 00:00:00', '15:16:17')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT EngagementNumber,
       StartDate,
       StartTime
FROM Engagements
WHERE StartDate >= '2017-10-01' and StartDate < '2017-11-01'
AND StartTime BETWEEN '12:00' AND '17:00'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/505281/3/0)**:

```
| EngagementNumber |            StartDate | StartTime |
|------------------|----------------------|-----------|
|                2 | 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z |  14:15:16 |
|                3 | 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z |  15:16:17 |
```

Please note that the same query would also work in SQL Server is the data types are the same as assumed here.

A final note. If the data types ARE date & time then they are NOT STRINGS (text) even if they might look like they are. So LIKE '2012-10%' will not work but storing date/time information as stings is NOT a good idea anyway.